# Deploying specific tagged image in openshift

Tags: jenkins, openshift, jenkins-pipeline, openshift-origin, openshift-3

Hi I am working on Openshift 3.9. Below is the piece of jenkins pipeline code

```
     stage('Build Image') {
        openshift.withCluster() {
            openshift.withProject(env.DEV_PROJECT) {
                        def bcSelector = openshift.selector("bc", "jboss")
                        def bcExists = bcSelector.exists()
                   if (!bcExists) { 
                    openshift.newBuild("--name=jboss", "--image-stream=jboss-eap70-openshift:1.5", "--binary=true") 
                   } else {echo "The specified image already exists"}                       
            }}
   }    
      stage('Build Image with app') {
        sh "rm -rf oc-build && mkdir -p oc-build/deployments"
        sh "cp /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/devpipeline/jobs/devpipeline-tasks-pipeline/workspace/target/hello-1.0.war oc-build/deployments/ROOT.war"                                
           openshift.withCluster() {
             openshift.withProject(env.DEV_PROJECT) {
               openshift.selector("bc", "jboss").startBuild("--from-dir=oc-build", "--wait=true")
             }
           }
      }
      stage('deploy to Dev') {
                              openshift.withCluster() {
          openshift.withProject(env.DEV_PROJECT) {
            if (openshift.selector('dc', 'jboss').exists()) {
              openshift.selector('dc', 'jboss').delete()
              openshift.selector('svc', 'jboss').delete()
              openshift.selector('route', 'jboss').delete()
            }

            def app = openshift.newApp("jboss:latest")
            app.narrow("svc").expose();
            def dc = openshift.selector("dc", "jboss")
           openshift.tag("${env.DEV_PROJECT}/jboss:latest", "${env.DEV_PROJECT}/jboss:${build_number}")
         }
    }
   }
```

In `Build` stage iam taking jboss container. In `Build Image with app` stage i am taking the war file which was built and building the image of jboss with war file.In `deploy to dev` i am deploying the application image into dev and tagging the image with jenkins build number `${env.DEV_PROJECT}/jboss:${build_number}`.I am working on the rollback mechanism in pipeline where in i want to deploy a specific build number image into dev environment. suppose if my jenkins build number is 14 and i want deploy 10 then how can i deploy specific tagged image into dev. In images of openshift i can see all the tagged images ranging from 1 to 14. Now i want to deploy specific tagged image into dev. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is change the DeploymentConfig with another version of the image you a deploying (:latest). You can do that in de web console with EDIT the deployment and choose another :tag from the image stream jboss.

Or with an oc patch command to change the DC

oc patch dc  --patch='{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"containers":[{"name": "", "image":"image-name:tag"}]}}}}'